# VBA Code breaks when looping

Tags: excel, vba, web

I have a small problem, I need to loop through excel rows

However, the code broke. If I am just running it step by step by cliking F8, it is ok. but if I want to run it just by F5, it breaks...

I guess it is not to fast to connect to external source, but how can I solve such problem?

```
lDate = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value 
With appIE 
    .Navigate "www.thisisjusttheexampleweb.com" 
    'it usually breaks here or below 
End With 

Do While appIE.Busy 
    DoEvents 
Loop 

'or it breaks here on setting allRowOfData 
Set allRowOfData = appIE.document.getElementById("Table") 
Set InterestingFields = allRowOfData.Children
```

Thanks for all the help

P.

Edit: I found other solution without parsing any web, what is more it is better to use some API to get the data for free, and very often the web's owners don't allow to parse/scrape any info from the web.

Comment: A couple thoughts.  1) Use their API, don't web scrape in order to get the data for free.  2) Don't use IE to scrape, get the data VIA XML, and parse the results.

Comment: @Purchawka, it's a very bad idea to edit your question and leave just "I found other solution". Even if you find another way, someone else might find your post useful (this is what SO is about) so please undo the edit and leave the originary question :)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Yes, you are right, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

As for the problem you're asking about in your question, the problem is that the browser changes its "Busy" status before the page is completely loaded. This might happen, so the statement:

```
Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop
```

gets out of the loop before the page is really loaded. What happens then? Well, when you try to set your statement:

```
Set allRowOfData = appIE.document.getElementById("historicalRateTb1")
```

...it fails because such element with the ID you look for is not in the document of your IE application yet. A "not very nice" way to solve this, but that should answer your question, usually consits of let the Excel application waiting some time before to run the rest of the code, so that the browser will have the material time to load the full page:

```
Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now())+5) 'this waits 5 seconds before the code run is restored
```

However, now that you seem to be a bit more acquainted with IE automation, my suggestion is to start learning the use of the so-called **XMLHTTP Request object**. Find more info about it [here](http://www.vba-and-excel.com/vba/internet/6-loading-information-from-the-internet-using-the-xmlhttp-object). I aware you in advance that:

- The good aspect of this object is the speed, since it queries the data in XML and is *way faster* than the human robotization of the browser to get the same HTML body where your data lie;
- The "bad" aspect, apart for the fact that the website might not provide this service, is that usually the object uses the cache to avoid the call; in other words, if you queried the data at 19:52, when you will query at 19:53 it will rather take the cached data of your browser at 19:52 and not the new data at 19:53. There should be a property into the object to avoid this, or you might just append a random number to the website string (that will not be read in the URL but will force the new query to the website).